# Understanding dplyr::filter Non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr

I think the problem has something to do with non-standard evaluation.
Please help me understand why the first method works and the second does not.
Thanks!

```
# Create a list of dataframes
all_data <- list("motors"=MASS::motors)
my_name <- "motors"

######## Works
df <- all_data[[my_name]]
new_df <- dplyr::filter(df, df$cens == 1)

####### doesn't work
new_df <- dplyr::filter(all_data[[my_name]], all_data[[my_name]]$cens == 1)
# Error: invalid subscript type 'integer'
```

Session info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-45    lazyeval_0.2.0 magrittr_1.5   R6_2.2.0       assertthat_0.1 DBI_0.5-1      tools_3.3.0    dplyr_0.5.0   
 [9] tibble_1.2     Rcpp_0.12.9
```

Comment: It works for you when you run the code?

Comment: Sure, the results are identical. Have you tried to run the code in a new session?

Comment: Yes, and it still doesn't work. I added session info.

Comment: FWIW, I got the same error you did with your script, but if you remove `all_data[[my_name]]$` it works as expected. So just `dplyr::filter(all_data[[my_name]], cens == 1)`. This is because you've already defined the data frame so there's no need to declare it again. That's the NSE part.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I ran the code the second first. But both works for dplyr ‘0.5.0.9001’

Comment: Still doesn't answer why the first method works and the second doesn't. Maybe I just don't understand NSE enough.